# Modification to a google timestamp script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

Have a working timestamp script that works for cells at a set col & row onwards, as users are only required to enter data in specific cells.

Need to modify it so that when cells in the `targetcolumn` are cleared so do the timestamps in datetime cells.

I believe it requires the addition of an else statement but I have yet to work out the corrected way.

```
function onEdit(e){

  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var dateTime = 4;
  var targetColumn = 9;
  var startRow = 19;
  var ws = "Tracking Sheet";

  if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === ws ) 
     {
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,dateTime).setValue(new Date());
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation:

- Indeed you need to implement a condition to check whether the new value of the edited cell is empty. If it is empty (which means the cell was cleared) then delete also the value in the `dateTime` column. Otherwise, update the value of `dateTime` column with the new date.
- To make your code more clear, I used a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) instead of a regular `if/else` statement:

  `e.range.getValue() == '' ?  range.setValue('') : range.setValue(new Date());`
- Finally, since you are using `e.source.getActiveSheet();` multiple times, it is a good idea to create a variable so you don't have to repeat yourself.

### Solution:

```
function onEdit(e){

  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var dateTime = 4;
  var targetColumn = 9;
  var startRow = 19;
  var ws = "Tracking Sheet";
  var as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  
  if(col === targetColumn && row >= startRow && as.getName() === ws ) 
     {
       let range = as.getRange(row,dateTime); 
       e.range.getValue() == '' ?  range.setValue('') : range.setValue(new Date());
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick edited script.  On further tweaking of the sheet I was wondering if it was possible to add the functionality of 2 target columns, e.g 9 & 10 thats would remove the timestamp if both targets were cleared of values?